# Filetype events in autocmd

Tags: vimrc

To run an autocommand on a python file I can do:

```
:autocmd FileType python     nnoremap ...
```

However, what 'event' does this run on? Is the event `FileType` or is `Filetype python` basically doing a replacement for `*.py` ? I would assume it's the former but I just wanted to understand the difference (if any) between doing the following two commands:

```
:autocmd FileType python     nnoremap ...
:autocmd FileType *.py       nnoremap ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autocmd FileType python` is run whenever the file type is set to `python`.

This happens for following files by default: `*.py`, `*.pyw` , `.pythonstartup` ,`.pythonrc`, `*.ptl` , `*.pyi` and `SConstruct`.

But it is also run when you change the filetype manually by executing `:setf python` or `:set ft=python`.